# How do I emulate an *encrypted* non-tamperable Viewstate in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, encryption, asp.net-mvc-4, viewstate

I have data that I only want to make available in three different HTTP POSTs (think of a workflow) and I don't want to use a QueryString, or a Cookie for this information.  For this reason, I think the concept of _viewstate applies here.

1. So, how should I emulate ViewState in ASP.NET MVC as a **encrypted** hidden field that includes confidentiality and authentication?
2. Does the ASP.NET 4 or newer framework include this?

More Information

ASP.NET used an encrypted Viewstate as a hidden field in a form.  One of the benefits of this is that the cryptography was "authenticated", meaning that any tampering would be detected in addition to the privacy features available in an encrypted payload.

There are many many questions on this site that discuss how to retrofit Viewstate into ASP.NET MVC, but no answers I've seen address the encryption of the data that includes these features to the serialized data:

- Confidentiality (privacy)
- Authentication (no modifications)

Comment: What is your primary objective here? do you want to keep hidden encrypted fields on form? if that is so what you want to achieve with those fields?

Comment: I don't think you understand what ViewState was, nor why it's irrelevant in MVC.

Comment: @AdilMughal I want to have an application that doesn't have server side state.  I need confidential information pertaining to the session to be associated with the current user (and session) and let that information persist among 5 pages.  I don't want to encrypt and store it in a cookie HTTP or otherwise.

Comment: @Dai  I want to store encrypted data in a hidden field in HTML on the client side.  I also want to encrypt it using machinekey or something similar. That is exactly what viewstate did.  Feel free to offer up an alternative (because that's what I'm asking for).

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't "Classic ASP" (which is the COM-heavy, VBScript-friendly platform that was popular from 1997 to 2003) but ASP.NET WebForms which used ViewState. ViewState itself was a Base64-encoded (not encrypted) representation of the page's controls' properties. This was done because HTML Forms don't transmit additional properties back to the server, only `<input>s`' `value=""` attributes, so the ViewState included things like a control's background color property (if it was set).

In WebForms, developers could use ViewState validation MAC to ensure their viewstate data wasn't altered, but in practice it frequently broke down. If you search for "Validation of viewstate MAC failed" then you'll find countless discussions on how to workaround the issue. However that is an irrelevant point in my post.

If you want to use a client form field as a roundtrip data vector, then that's perfectly fine, just do something like the code below.

```
class PageViewModel {
    public String SecretData;
}

public ActionResult Foo() {

    Byte[] someSecretData = GetIcbmLaunchCodes();
    someSecretData = ArbitraryEncryptionAlgorithm( someSecretData ); // you can encrypt the data any way you want. I personally recommend a symmetric algorithm like AES or TripleDES.

    HashAlgorithm hashAlgo = new HMACSHA1();
    hashAlgo.Key = /* Your private key for HMAC */
    Byte[] hmac = hashAlgo.ComputeHash( someSecretData );

    // when using SHA1, hmac will be 160 bits long, or 20 bytes.
    PageViewModel model = new PageViewModel();
    model.SecretData = Convert.ToBase64String( hmac + someSecretData ); // array concatenation is an exercise for the reader
    return View( model );
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(PageViewModel model) {

    Byte[] postedData = Convert.FromBase64String( model.SecretData );

    Byte[] hmac = postedData[0...20]; // array substring is an exercise for the reader
    Byte[] secretData = postedData[20...n];

    // Now verify the secret data
    HashAlgorithm hashAlgo = new HMACSHA1();
    hashAlgo.Key = /* Your private key for HMAC */
    Byte[] hmac2 = hashAlgo.ComputeHash( secretData );

    if( hmac2 != hmac ) {
        /* the data has been tampered with. */
    } else {
        /* the data is unadulterated */

        Byte[] originalSecretData = ArbitaryDecryptionAlgorithm( secretData );
    }

}
```

Comment: If you are using .net 4.5 I would suggest the following to product the data: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx

Comment: @RossDargan - Anything that uses DPAPI will break a load balancer, since the private keys are not shared across all nodes in the farm

Comment: True, in which case you should use MachineKey.Protect/Unprotect http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee360267.aspx :-)